# Dataframe printed as Empty Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

All I want to do is create a new dataframe with a certain value in the "Invoice Date" column, then print that dataframe. But when I print it, it returns an "Empty Dataframe" with all the columns and no index. How can I fix this problem?

```
date = input("date? ")
    dates = pd.Series(list("Invoice Date"))
    while not dates[dates.isin([date])].empty:
        date = input("date? ")
df2 = df.loc[df["Invoice Date"] == date]
print(df2)
```

Comment: Can you add what `df` is and what data is being searched in `df2`? Basically, any example?

Comment: Did you try and print the value of `dates = pd.Series(list("Invoice Date"))`? I don't think its showing you what you expected